# Como accedo al objeto, al que le quiero aplicar el updateView?

Tags: django, django-forms

Ok, necesito acceder al objeto al que le estoy haciendo el update view, enviandole 2 variantes especiales, que manipulo primeramente en el DOM, mediante js, ok sucede, que cuando voy a aplicar los cambios, se me guardan a mi y no al record, al que le estoy haciendo el updateView. Ademas mediante un hidden input ¿Como accedo al campo de un usuario en especifico mediante el id de la solciitud?

Mi función

```
def update_permisos(request, pk):
    p = get_object_or_404(Permiso, pk=pk)
    form = Permiso_update(request.POST, instance=p)
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():    
        if form.is_valid():
            permiso = form.save(commit=False)
            permiso.usuario = request.user
            permiso.save()
            permiso.usuario.d_pendientes = request.POST['d_pendientes']#valores, que van al campo
            permiso.usuario.h_pendientes = request.POST['h_pendientes']#valores, que van al campo
            permiso.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'true', 'msg':'Datos procesados correctamente'})#retornando JSon en jsConsole 
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'false', 'msg':'Datos procesados incorrectamente'})#retornando respuesta en jsConsole
    else:
        form = Permiso_update(instance=p)
        asrg = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'plantillas/permisos_update.html', asrg)
```

Mi formulario .html

```
<form method="POST" id="permi">
{% csrf_token %}
<h6>{{ form.as_p }}</h6>
<input type="hidden" id="const_dias" name="d_pendientes" value="{{ 
Users.usuario.d_pendientes }}">
<input type="hidden" id="const_horas" name="h_pendientes" value="{{ Users.usuario.h_pendientes }}"> 
<button type="submit">Guardar</button>
```

Como puedo acceder a la información de cada usuario mediante el id de la solicitud en los campos hidden que tengo en el archivo html o hay alguna u otra forma de hacer esto . Agradezco sus comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas son tareas asíncronas, lo puede hacer usando ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function funcion(parametro1, parametro2){
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/ruta_url/metodo_o_clase/'+parametro1,
            traditional: true,
            data: {
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                 acciones del método
                 }
                 $("#"+paramentro2).html(options);
             }
        });
   }
</script>
```